# Promise MongoDB Trying Connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, promise

Is this a good way to connect to mongoDB from a nodejs dockerized application? Sometimes mongoDb docker is no ready, so I need to try to connect again to be sure mongoDb  docker container is ready and keep executing the following promises.

docker_compose.yaml file already has a dependency defined between applicacion and mongoDB.

Cheers!

```
private connect() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.DB_HOST}/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false}, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                log.error(err.message);
                setTimeout(this.connect, 1000);
            } else {
                log.info('--> App Connected to MongoDb');
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}
private init() {
    const promises = [
        () => this.connect(),
        () => this.loadConfig(),
        () => this._webHookService.init(),
        () => this._cronService.init()
    ];

    return promises.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn).catch(error => log.error(error)), Promise.resolve());
}
```

Comment: On error `reject(err)` and leave retrying to a higher level function.

Comment: Also introduce (1) delay between retries (say 500ms), (2) a limit on the number of retries (say 10). Do these in the higher level caller.

Comment: The fact is that the shown code works, but I need to know if its right the way that it has been done. Either, as you said @Roamer-1888, calling reject() is missing. I understand you, but I don't figure out how to fit your solution into the typescript code. Cheers!